# Размер элементов структуры

Tags: c++, c

Как определить сколько байт требуется на выделение памяти под переменную, например, в структуре, для экономии памяти?

Пример:

```
//без задания размера
struct DATETIME
{
  usigned short Year;
  usigned short Month;
  usigned short Date;
}

//с заданием размера
struct DATETIME
{
  usigned short Year   : 7; //значения меняются от 0 до 99
  usigned short Month  : 4; //значения меняются от 0 до 12
  usigned short Date   : 5; //значения меняются от 0 до 31
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите на ходу узнавать размер поля или вы хотите понять, как получить саму величину размера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То что Вы используете в пункте "с заданием размера" - это битовые поля. Т.е. можно сделать переменные, которые будут размером на кратным байту. В результате компилятор их упакует. Посчитать количество битов, которые нужно выделить легко. Вспоминаем, что бит может иметь 2 значения, два бита - 4 и т.д. по степеням двойки. Т.е. нам нужно взять двоичный логарифм от кол-ва значений и округлить до бОльшего целого. Пример: 32 значения -> 32=2^5. Итого - нам нужно 5 битов для представления 32-х разных значений (в диапазоне от 0 до 31).

Answer (score 0):

Битовые поля .-. Не экономьте на спичках, будет лучше.

Если вам надо 7 бит - так берите однобайтовый тип. Ближайший кратный 8.
Минимальный размер в битах определяется количеством возможных значений данного поля. Двоичный логарифм от количества.

Расположение полей структуры тоже будет влиять на размер её - есть такая штука как выравнивание. Хотя, это всё настраиваемо.